# why my code for printing fibonacci series does not work if i have to print a large amount of them?

Tags: c

here is my code to print fibonacci series

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
 long int i,firstno=1,secondno=1;

 printf("%d\n%d\n",firstno,secondno);
 for(i=0;i<8;i++){
     int temp = secondno;
      secondno = secondno+firstno;
        firstno = temp;

 printf("%d\n",firstno);
 }return 0;
 }
```

it works fine if i have to print say first 90 fibonacci numbers but it starts giving large garbage values if i have to print say 200000 of them? why does this happen ?how can i stop this and improve my code?

Comment: Because of the size of long int.

Comment: you can refer to the table by TCS Web and try with `unsigned long`

Comment: Use `%ld` to print `long`.

Answer (score 4):

Value you have giving to the variable that will exceed the maximum range of the long int. So this is the reason for printing the garbage value.

Answer (score 2):

Because your variable exceeds the maximum range of the long int. So this is the reason for printing the garbage value.

See the table below for storage size and value range:

```
Type          | Storage size |  Value range
____________________________________________________________
char          | 1 byte       |  -128 to 127 or 0 to 255
unsigned char | 1 byte       |  0 to 255
signed char   | 1 byte       |  -128 to 127
int           | 2 or 4 bytes |  -32,768 to 32,767 or -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
unsigned int  | 2 or 4 bytes |  0 to 65,535 or 0 to 4,294,967,295
short         | 2 bytes      |  -32,768 to 32,767
unsigned short| 2 bytes      |  0 to 65,535
long          | 4 bytes      |  -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
unsigned long | 4 bytes      |  0 to 4,294,967,295
```

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting an overflow! A 64-bit value just isn't large enough once you reach fib(30) or thereabouts.

You need to use an arbitrary size integer library if you want to be able to produce arbitrary size output.

If you look at the answers you're getting, and you convert them into hexadecimal, you'll find that they're correct as far as they go: you've got the right lower-order bits, but the high bits are being lopped off every time an arithmetic operation overflows.

You'll be out by a multiple of 2<sup>32</sup>, or whatever the size of a `long int` is on your platform.

Comment: so what do you suggest.how do i correct it?.should i use long double ?

Comment: No, you need to find a library to use that allows for *arbitrary size* integers. Even a `long long` is fixed size.